# Sed Pattern does not yield expected result

Tags: sed

I have a file with a lot of SQL INSERT constructs. I am trying to write a sed script to extract lines containing the INSERT table name.

```
   INSERT INTO Table1 values( val1, vale2, val3 );

    INSERT INTO Table2
    VALUES( val1, vale2, val3 );

    INSERT
    INTO
    Table3
    VALUES( val1, vale2, val3 );

    insert into table4
    SELECT col1 from
    table4
    where condition1 = condition2
    ;
    INSERT
    INTO
    table5 (col1, col2, col3)
    VALUES( val1, vale2, val3 );

    insert into table6 (col1,
    col2,
    col3, col4
    )
    SELECT col1, col2, col3,
    col4 FROM
    table6
    WHEREcondition1 = condition2
    ;
```

My output should be:

```
 insert into table4
 insert into table6
```

This is what i have tried. I am however not sure why my sed patterns are not working. The script is picking up lines which donot have the SELECT word.  I am using GNU sed 4.2.  Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
# select all lines between INSERT and ; 
sed -n '/Insert/I,/;/ {
#delete the blank line
/^\s*$/{
i\ ...deleting blank line
=
d}
#selecting sub pattern range between INTO and SELECT
/into/I, /Select/I {
i\
...inside the Into---Select range
p
}
}' < testfile
```

My current output from the above is:

```
...inside the Into---Select range
INSERT INTO Table1 select values( val1, vale2, val3 );
 ...deleting blank line
120
...inside the Into---Select range
INSERT INTO Table2
...inside the Into---Select range
values( val1, vale2, val3 );
...inside the Into---Select range
INSERT
...inside the Into---Select range
 INTO
...inside the Into---Select range
Table3
...inside the Into---Select range
values( val1, vale2, val3 );
...inside the Into---Select range
insert into table4
...inside the Into---Select range
SELECT col1 from
...inside the Into---Select range
 INTO
...inside the Into---Select range
Table5 (col1, col2, col3)
...inside the Into---Select range
values( val1, vale2, val3 );
...inside the Into---Select range
insert into table6 (col1,
...inside the Into---Select range
col2,
...inside the Into---Select range
col3, col4
...inside the Into---Select range
)
...inside the Into---Select range
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
```

Comment: Why in your example is table5 outputted when there is no select statement?

Comment: Have you tried using `awk` for this instead of `sed`? It tends to work better on multi-line input.

Comment: @bkmoney you are right. It should not. I have corrected the output.

Comment: @Etan, since SED was already being used, tried it with SED only.

Comment: @Samar I see you are new to SO. As there are many answers to your question, please consider accepting one if you find it suitable.

Comment: @BK. sure I did. The answers were little overwhelming  for a SED starter like me to decipher. So I took some time to mark them. anyways great posts and amazing knowledge out there!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr '/insert/I{:a;/;/!{$!{N;ba}};s/^\s*(insert\s+into\s+\S+)\s+(\([^)]*\))*\s*select.*/\l\1/i;T;s/\s+/ /gp}' file
```

Use seds `-nr` switches to invoke grep-like nature and easier to read regexp. Ignore lines that do not contain `insert` (in lower or upper case). Append following lines until the pattern space includes a terminating `;`. Pattern match on the line(s) looking for `insert into tablename ... select` and if matched replace the line with the lowercase result. If pattern matching failed bail out otherwise replace all whitespace with spaces and print.

Comment: Thanks Potong. This was the closest to my need. I however need few clarifications: is \S  for string class? what \l and T means?

Comment: If you look at my sample file, you would see few INSERT construct are made up of  'values' word. So I added (select|values). I however noticed for the INSERT with 'values' word had their only first word changed to lower case. Though it is not a probelm, I would like to understand why? this is the output:  iNSERT INTO Table1
iNSERT INTO Table2

Comment: I got to know \l and \S except 'T'. As you said it is for the bail out.  Is it kind of branching without a label?

Comment: I just tried your sed command without 'T'. It works and no diff in the output.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -rn 'H;1h;/;/!d;x; s/.*insert[[:space:]]+into[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]+([(][^)]*[)][[:space:]]+)?select.*/insert into \1/Ip' file
insert into table4
insert into table6
```

#### How it works

- `-r`

  This tells sed to use extended regular expression syntax.
- `-n`

  This tells sed not to print anything unless we explicitly ask it to.
- `H;1h;/;/!d;x;`

  This reads reads all lines into the pattern space stopping with the first line that has a semicolon.

  In more detail, `H;1h` appends each line we read into the hold space.  If the line does not contain `;`, then we delete the line (command `d`).  This has the effect of telling sed to skip the rest of the commands and to start over with the next line.  If we get to the `x` command, that means that the last line contains a semicolon, `;`.  `x` swaps everything that we have saved in the hold space back to the pattern space.
- `s/.*insert[[:space:]]+into[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]+([(][^)]*[)][[:space:]]+)?select.*/insert into \1/Ip`

  This searches the line to find the word after `into` and before `select` and prints it.  To achieve your desired output, this command optionally allows a parenthesized expression between to occur before `select`.

#### Alternate version using ranges

```
$ sed -rn '/insert/I,/;/{H;/;/!d;x; s/.*insert[[:space:]]+into[[:space:]]+([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]+([(][^)]*[)][[:space:]]+)?select.*/insert into \1/Ip}' file
insert into table4
insert into table6
```

Comment: I just tried this line to see what it prints. sed -nr '/insert/I{H;1h;/;/!d;x;p}' < test

Comment: I am not sure if i understand its output. It adds a blank line. table1 is duplicated. prints only first line of table2. same for table3. table 5 is completely omitted.                     /**** output  -----blank line-----
INSERT INTO Table1 values( val1, vale2, val3 );
INSERT INTO Table1 values( val1, vale2, val3 );
INSERT INTO Table2
INSERT
insert into table4
INSERT
insert into table6 (col1, *******/

Comment: @Samar To begin, what OS are you using?  Linux uses GNU sed and OSX uses BSD sed and the two have differences.

Comment: It is Linux x86_64 GNU/Linux,  and GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: @Samar I cannot reproduce the output that you see but the `/insert/I` means that that code only applies to lines that contain `/insert/`.  If you do want to use line selection, it should be a range. I added to the end of the answer a version of the code that only processes ranges of lines that start with `/insert/I` and end with `/;/`.

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the help extended.

Answer (score 1):

If you put this into j.sed

```
#n
/INSERT/{
    :loop
    /;/!{
        N
        b loop      
    }
    /SELECT/{
        :l2
        s/\([^a]*able.\).*/\1/
        p
        b
    }
    /select/b l2
}
/insert/b loop
```

And run

```
sed -f j.sed foo.txt
```

This will output

```
insert into table4
insert into table6
```

**Explanation**

The `#n` suppresses normal output.

The `/INSERT/` matches the insert, and starts a branch called `loop`. Until we reach the semicolon, it appends the next line to the pattern space using `N`.

If the pattern space matches `SELECT` or `select`, we go to a branch called `l2`, which deletes everything after the "insert into tablex". We print out the line using `p`, and go to the end of the script with `b`.

The `/insert/ b loop` just branches to `loop` if it matches lowercase "insert".

Comment: I could follow the first part where you are appending all lines into the current pattern space until word ;.  then search for SELECT and print the first part based on the 'table'. Could you please explain this logic in detail? since the table names do not start with 'table', this may require change based on 'INTO';

Comment: `:loop
    /;/!{
        N
        b loop      
    }` What this does is starts a branch called `loop`, and the `/;/!` means matching NOT a semicolon, then we append with `N`, and go back to the beginning of `loop`

Comment: After we have reached the semicolon, we check if the pattern space matches select,

`/SELECT/{
        :l2
        s/\([^a]*able.\).*/\1/
        p
        b
    }`

If we match "select", we start a new branch called `l2`, and what `s/\([^a]*able.\).*/\1/` does is that it captures from the beginning of the line to tablex, and replaces the whole line with this captured group. We print out the edited line, and go to the end of the script with `b`

Comment: thanks bk. your post showed me as how to use sed commands in a file. though one question puzzles me as why the nested pattern matching fails in this case.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a nested pattern where this fails?

Comment: sed -nr '/Insert/I,/;/{ /^\s*$/{d};/into/I,/Select/I{p};}' < test prints all insert lines with table1, table2, table3 and table5.  the idea was to get first all lines within 'INSERT' and ';' Then print lines between 'INTO' and 'SELECT' of each selection.